# Material UI : making underlined tabs

Tags: user-interface, material-ui

I need to make a design like this, which material UI component should i be using ?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Material-ui Tabs

https://codesandbox.io/s/cbn97

https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#tabs

```
<AppBar position="static">
  <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="simple tabs example">
    <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
    <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
    <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
  </Tabs>
</AppBar>
<TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
  Item One
</TabPanel>
<TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
  Item Two
</TabPanel>
<TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
  Item Three
</TabPanel>
```